# How to add two global variables to a groovy file?

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am writing Jenkins shared-libraries and I have a issue with a script file.

I have the following groovy file into vars/myFile.groovy (this file is an script file that only contains functions "as jenkins docs mention it: [https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries"](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries%22))

```
import org.utils.MyClassOne
import org.utils.MyClassTwo
import groovy.transform.Field

@Field MyClassOne myclassOne = new MyClassOne(this)
@Field MyClassTwo myclassTwo = new MyClassTwo(this)

void myFunction(){
   myclassOne.printMessage("some message")
   myclassTwo.printMessage("some message")
}
```

This is the content of the two classes into "src" folder

```
class MyClassOne {
  
  Script script
   
  MyClassOne(Script script){
     this.script = script
  }

  void printMessage(String message){
      this.script.println(message)     
  }
}

class MyClassTwo {
  
  Script script
   
  MyClassTwo(Script script){
     this.script = script
  }

  void printMessage(String message){
      this.script.println(message)     
  }
}
```

The issue is that I can call the "printMessage" method from the first class "MyClassOne" but I cannot call to the second "printMessage" method from the my second class "MyClassTwo" and I wondering why?

Any help will be welcome

Comment: MyClassTwo has a wrong constructor.

Comment: Yes, my bad, I wrote it wrong when I wrote the question, in my code the constructor it is ok but still have the issue